# Bat file help - Trying to cerate new folder->copyAll->add Timestamp - Testdata mangement

Tags: batch-file, automated-tests

So I work as a manual tester and I'm trying to automate some...

This is what I'm trying to achive:

1. Copying all xml files and adding timestamp to files (including subfolders)
2. Moving it to a new folder name "TestRun todaysdate"
   ----This I have not yet achived....
3. Reading the result from specific table from SQL table
4. Name = result pass or fail logic
5. Present result where how?

Right now I'm stuck on the first step.... creating a batchfile that copies all folders and adding the timestamp:
This is what I have right now (you se only adding timestamp, not included sub folders):

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%

SET NETWORKSOURCE=\\lfnas22204\home\lfab_1\B9988\SYSTEM\Desktop\"AMA Filter 2021" 
REN %NETWORKSOURCE% /S.xml "????????????????????????????????????????????????? - %stamp%.xml"
```

pause

Comment: Do you think the `REN` command has an `/S` option?  If you read the help file it most certainly does not.  You have to put the entire file path together with the rename command as well. That includes the file name or file mask. Have no idea what you are trying to do with all the wildcards. You will need to use a `FOR` command to do what you want to do.

Comment: Best practice for assigning a value to a varialbe: `SET "NETWORKSOURCE=\\lfnas22204\home\lfab_1\B9988\SYSTEM\Desktop\AMA Filter 2021"`

Comment: Could you also clarify whether you want each of the files to have exactly the same date and time string? or whether each is supposed to have the date and time of their rename. _(time moves on and you cannot expect everything to be renamed within the period before the next second!)_

Comment: What I want is: copy folder with all sub folders and all the XML files in the folders, add today's date on the end of original file name.